# Failed to fetch at sendData (token.js:32:5) at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (form.js:56:13)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fetch

I have a login form for an ecommerce website made with node + express which contains an email and a password input, when i press the submit button it gives me this "failed to fetch" error

Here's the sendData function from `token.js` file

```
const sendData = (path, data) => {
    fetch(path, {
        method: 'post',
        headers: new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'}),
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    }).then((res) => res.json())
    .then(response => {
        processData(response);
    })
}
```

And here is the code from form.js (i have an if for the signup page and this else is for login page)

```
else {
        // login page
        if(!email.value.length || !password.value.length) {
            showAlert('fill all the inputs');
        } else {
            loader.style.display = 'block';
            sendData('/login', {
                email: email.value,
                password: password.value,
            })
        }
}
```

Also, my node server is not working, i expect it to type an email and a password from the database and to be redirected to the `index.html` page (main page). Can somebody help me please?

Comment: looks like CORS problem, at least from information given, if your site runs on http://127.0.0.1 in can be CORS, you need to change it to http://localhost  something like `server.listen(3000, 'localhost');` But I still not understand your app structure, so can be wrong.

Comment: I need screenshot of console with error, and screentshot of chrome devtools network tab with sent request in it